# systemd-resolved: ResolveUnicastSingleLabel= missing in 20.04?

Tags: server, 20.04, systemd, systemd-resolved

I am trying to get systemd-resolved to resolve single-label querries/hostnames.

As far as I understand systemd-resolved, it just drops request like `dig randomhostname` because no fqdn is provided.

if I understand https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-resolved.service.html# correctly, adding `ResolveUnicastSingleLabel=yes` to `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` should enable querying of single-label domain names via the set up dns.

However systemd-resolved complains about the option not being valid.

> /etc/systemd/resolved.conf:24: Unknown key name 'ResolveUnicastSingleLabel' in section 'Resolve', ignoring.

/etc/systemd/resolved.conf

```
[Resolve]
ResolveUnicastSingleLabel=yes
```

Am I doing something wrong or is ubuntu using a different version of systemd-resolved???

Comment: Everything that is supported in `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` can be found in `man resolved.conf`.

Comment: then Ubuntu 20.04 does not support "ResolveUnicastSingleLabel=yes". Then how do I qery single-label hostnames?

Comment: Maybe this will help you:  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/482348/how-single-label-dns-lookup-requests-are-handled-by-systemd-resolved

Comment: @Flaep, please... just upvote a comment when it is helpful, so as to avoid comments such as just a "thanks" kind of statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My conclusion is, that if "ResolveUnicastSingleLabel=yes" is not available or configured single-label      requests are dropped.

To have them resolved they need to be part of a domain and search=/domain= for that domain need to be set up.

To "solve" my problem I disabled systemd-resolved and use plain /etc/resolv.conf. Not the solution I wanted but the one that works. :(